# SDL_Events how to make it

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I wrote a func that help me move my car with SDL

```
if (events.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch(events.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_UP:
                y_val -=main_car_speed;
                break;
            case SDLK_DOWN:
                y_val +=main_car_speed;
                break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                x_val +=main_car_speed;
                break;
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                x_val -=main_car_speed;
                break;
        }
```

It's pretty simple. But I got a problem that when I press up and left. My car just go ahead, instead of go ahead and left at the sametime. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Instrumentalise for debugging, i.e. print each recognised event. Make sure that all the events are detected, then review the logic of reacting to them.

Comment: There is not enough code in question to answer that. How and when do you get events? How do you handle key release? How do you perform movement?

Answer (score 0):

Using events, if you press 'left' after having pressed 'up', your program will stop receiving events for the 'up' key-presses and will instead receive only 'left' key-presses. If you want to know whether keys are pressed or not pressed at any moment in time, rather than react to when they are first pressed, the following code should help you:

```
// inside main loop, after events have been handled

const Uint8* keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]){
    y_val -= main_car_speed;
}
if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]){
    x_val -= main_car_speed;
}
```

Have a look at the [Documentation for SDL_GetKeyboardState](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) for details

Comment: Thanks bro. But it's not my problem. When i press up first then press left. My program just receive the up button only instead of both up and left. Then my car just go ahead.

Comment: I want my game go both left and straight ahead when I press both left button and up button.

Comment: That's not possible using SDL events, you'll need to use key states as described above. Take a close look at http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/18_key_states/index.php for an example usage

Comment: It's not possible using events for much the same reason that pressing and holding 'a', then pressing and holding 'b' in any text editor will only continue typing 'b'. That may help illustrate how the operating system sends keyboard events to your program.